# Laravel with input respond

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to achieve callback message on redirect if you done something. I found that it can be passed like this (in Controller):

```
return redirect()
      ->route('users')
      ->withInput()->with('status', 'Something Updated!');
```

How it can be achieved in other end after being redirected?
My first question on slack - ty, guys :)

Comment: In the blade file, you will get the value in $status

Answer (score 0):

On the blade file, you can get the value in `with` using session. Here is the example from the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```